# Asp.net MongoDB ToListAsync() Never Returns

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asynchronous

I've spent hours trying to debug this but no luck.  I'm using Mongo 3.2 with the C# driver.  I've reduced the problem into a simplified version that still displays the problem.

The issue seems to be that ToListAsync() never returns.  I've tried changeing the LoginHelper function to synchronous and checking the value of ToListAsync().Result to verify the operation returns the proper document and it does.  Not sure why this async version won't work though.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static async Task<string> LoginUser(string username, string password)
    {
        string userId = await LoginHelper(username, password);

        if (userId != "N/A")
        {
            //Do some stuff here
        }

        return userId;
    }

    public static async Task<string> LoginHelper(string userName, string password)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var database = client.GetDatabase(_databaseName);

        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");

        //This is the trouble line
        //If I remove this line the code will run fine and I'll see "N/A" returned in the JavaScript that calls LoginUser WebMethod
        var documents = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();

        //The code never reaches this point, the above await never returns
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use FindAsync instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue simply by moving the functionality into a WCF web service instead of using a web method.  I'm not sure why this works, perhaps Webmethods in an ASPX page aren't compatible with async.